# asp.net OnTextChanged not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've got a few OnTextChanged events which aren't firing. The PostBack is set to true, and they're being changed (with the current date/time) from other bits in the asp.net / java code. Their values are being changed, so the events should fire but they're not:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="lblRoute" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="btnRoute_Click" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="White" Width="5px"></asp:TextBox>
```

As I mention, the value of this textbox is changing (and it is visible, but made to look like it isn't - it exists purely to fire it's event) but the event isn't being fired.

EDIT - just to fill in some more blanks, a user presses a button in this manner:

```
<button id="btnRoute" onclick="GetRoute(); return false;" runat="server" style="width: 30%">Route</button>
```

The button calls this, eventually (as I mention, this is being called as the label is being changed):

```
document.getElementById("lblRoute").value = Date.now();
```

Which changes the label lblRoute, which *should* fire our event (and yes, the called function does exist). So far it looks like I may need to change the focus, as others have said, after the label has been changed in order to fire it. Any ideas how I'd do that?

Comment: Take into account that will post to server when textbox loses focus, not when content changes

Comment: see this question [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842384/asp-net-textbox-textchanged-and-button-onclick-event-interaction)

Comment: Hi are you sure that event exists in your code behind? OnTextChanged="btnRoute_Click" i think isn't correct do it. If the information in textbox change event fire when you change focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '`OnTextChanged`' event of the `asp:TextBox` is fired only when your textbox loses the focus.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx:

> The TextChanged event is raised when the content of the text box
>   changes between posts to the server.

The page will not post back immediately after the text is changed, but it will post back when the textbox loses focus.